# switch from mobile version to desktop version in mobile

Tags: html, media-queries

**I create a mobile version of my website with the help of media query, is that any way to switch from mobile version to desktop version in mobile? please tell me..**

Comment: Using CSS only, you could force desktop version by adding/removing some `class` to/from `body` that would prevent `media quaries` to be in use (selectors wouldn't select). Although, I think this would be a bad practice and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: then please tell me what is the complete solution on it how i create mobile version of my site

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide us with information on whathaveyoutried.com, and maybe someone is able to help you. In the meantime, I suggest that you check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. You could do add the media queries in different stylesheet and disable the stylesheet with Javascript or PHP.

I would suggest that you do it with PHP, as javascript can be disabled.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['nomobile'])){
// don't echo the stylesheet
}
else{
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaqueries.css">';
}
?>
```

This method uses a cookie, so to disable the mobile version of the page, you should create a link to a page `nomobile.php` or similar, depending on your skill level.

The contents of the `nomobile.php` could be something like:

```
<?php
setcookie("nomobile", true, time()+3600);
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com");
?>
```

---

`nomobile.php` sets a cookie that will expire within an hour (60*60 = 3600), and redirect to the index page of the site.

`<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['nomobile'])){` checks for the cookie, if it's set, it will not print the stylesheet to the page, and user will see a full version of the page. If the cookie is not set, all media queries apply.